# multiple log levels in same log file in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

How can multiple log levels added to the same log file in log4j?
For example:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,WARN,stdout,file
```

It gives the log4j error when application start as:

```
Could not instantiate appender named WARN.
```

Comment: Just configure the highest level. So in this case INFO. It will log INFO , WARN, ERROR and FATAL.

Comment: What about I want debug also?

Comment: DEBUG is higher than INFO. So if you want it, too, configure DEBUG. See it as a "<=".

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the threshold is to tell log4j to ignore all logging requests with a priority *lower* than what you specify.  Specifying a given threshold does not limit you to logging with that threshold.

```
FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
fa.setThreshold(Level.INFO);
fa.setAppend(true);
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fa);
```

In the above code, the appender has been configured to operate with a threshold of `INFO`.  This means that the following code will *not* log, because `DEBUG` is a lower priority than `INFO`:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);
logger.debug("This will not log");
```

But this code *will* log:

```
logger.warn("This debug message will log.");
logger.error("And this error message will also log.");
```

In this case, both `WARN` and `ERROR` have a higher priority than `INFO`.

Comment: Isn't it "FATAL, ERROR, WARN, **INFO, DEBUG**, ALL" ?